# OS "Forgets" User Passwords

Tags: password

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to host our FOG Server and I am not very familiar with Linux.

FOG is very particular about user names and passwords for it to work properly. It has worked well for the last 5 years, but this year we migrated it to a better computer. Since then, the user passwords are being forgotten or reset on a regular basis. I have to go into recovery because I am unable to get in.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a weird bug?

Comment: "Forgotten password" is usually a user problem.  When you reset, do you require the user to use a different password in case the old one was compromised?

Comment: In this case I am the user. I will use the main administrator password and password for the other user account, but every now and then the passwords just don't work anymore. I have changed the password in the terminal and logged out, when I try to log back in, it does not accept it.

Comment: Copy the /etc/shadow, and check the hash for the user with a problem.  If it changes, you don't have a "forgotten" type of problem, but an intruder/malware.